# R: Finding a repeated pattern with grep/gsub

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I'm trying to use the grep and gsub commands in R to find repeated chunks within a string. For example, I might have something like this...

```
z <- c("ab;cd;ef;gh;ij;kl;mn;mn;", "ab;cd;ef;gh;ij;kl;op;")
```

I want to identify the strings that have the repeated substrings between the semicolons. So in this case I want to get back z[1] and perhaps later change it to "ab;cd;ef;gh;ij;kl;mn;". I know I can use the memory slots in gsub to do something like so...

```
gsub("(.*mn;).*;", "\\1", z)
```

But that won't work when I don't know where the repeat is or what the repeated substring is. What I'd like to do is something like this...

```
gsub(";([^;]*;)\\1;", "\\1", z)
```

To produce this...

```
[1] "ab;cd;ef;gh;ij;kl;mn;" "ab;cd;ef;gh;ij;kl;op;"
```

Ideas?

Comment: Something like `lapply(strsplit(z,";"),anyDuplicated)` would certainly help you do what you want...

Comment: What happened to the nice answer using only `gsub`: I think it was something like `gsub("([^;]*;)\\1;?", "\\1", z)`?

Comment: @VincentGuillemot, that is the right solution, post it as an answer

Comment: @VincentGuillemot and everyone - you're right - I screwed up the regex since what I have would expect two `;`'s in the pattern.

Comment: I can't take credit for this answer: it was posted a few minutes ago but mysteriously disappeared. There is even a [demo here](http://regex101.com/r/pN7yM2/3). I just added the "?"...

Comment: @VincentGuillemot, it disappeared because in its previous version it didn't work.

Comment: The previous one didn't work - it was the `?` that made the difference.

Comment: commands to use in this context (identifying substrings and strings): `gsub()` and `grep()`.  Help with regular expressions to put into your patterns: http://www.endmemo.com/program/R/gsub.php    

However, there are some deficiencies in this explanation.  For example, you can't find the decimal in a pattern like "9.2" where 9.2 is a string using '\.' as one might expect from reading the help.  Oddly, you can solve the problem with just '\\d.\\d*' where this pattern indicates an unknown number of digits after the decimal.

Comment: reverse engineering an answer someone else posted on here:
`gsub("([^;]*;)\\1;?", "\\1", z)`   

The () creates a saved substring in the "find this" argument that you can then identify as \\1 when you want to reference it in your replace string.  This too is a deficiency in the link I provided above.  I was looking for help on this and it was not easy to find so thanks to the poster for that bit of help.  Hope you find this helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose the following modification of a previous answer using `gsub`

```
gsub("([^;]*;)\\1;?", "\\1", z)
```

This one also works and is maybe more correct

```
gsub("([^;]*;)\\1", "\\1", z)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would just do something like this

```
sapply(strsplit(z, ";"), function(x) paste(unique(x), collapse = ";"))
## [1] "ab;cd;ef;gh;ij;kl;mn" "ab;cd;ef;gh;ij;kl;op"
```

A bit better version (thanks to @CasimiretHippolyte)

```
sapply(strsplit(z, "(?<=;)", perl = T), function(x) paste(unique(x), collapse = ""))
## [1] "ab;cd;ef;gh;ij;kl;mn;" "ab;cd;ef;gh;ij;kl;op;"
```

Comment: i think op wants `;` after to `mn` and `op`

Comment: A "bad" way would be to artificially add an empty string at the end of the vector before collapsing: `sapply(strsplit(z, ";"), function(x) paste(c(unique(x),""), collapse = ";"))`

Comment: since it removes the terminal `;` i could just `paste0` it back onto the back end of every string. while this works, i was hoping for something more generalizable that would work with grep/grepl as well to identify those strings with the repeats. ideas?

Comment: @VincentGuillemot, this is just proposed as a workaround, you should post your `gsub` solution as it seems to be the correct one

Comment: You can use `(?<=;)` to split the string or `;\K`